# When to use $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ and when $(a_i)_{i\in I}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I was wondering: are

$\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$

and

$(a_i)_{i\in I}$

simply different notations for the different (?) sets/lists

$\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_I\}$

and

$(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_I)$,

respectively, or do they stand for different things (like rows)?

I.e., is this just a matter of taste/notation (and if so, is one of them more "standard"?) or is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: It might depend on the author. I am more used to see the first for a sequence and the second for a matrix/vector, which at the end is the same thing. But I would always look at the beginning of the book what the author really means.

Comment: Your notation $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_I\}$ does not make sense. There is no element $a_I$ (the indices are **elements** of the set $I$), and in general, there is no last element.

Comment: @azimut True, I probably should have written something like $\mathcal{I}=\{1,\ldots,I\}$ and $(a_i)_{i\in\mathcal{I}}=\{a_1,\ldots,a_I\}$ - but I thinks the question was understood nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ represents a sequence  while $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ represents a tuple if $|I|$ is finite(not necessary). There is not much difference.

Comment: Personally I use the notation $(a_ i)_{i\in I}$ for a sequence but I saw several person in this site use the other notation and I think that depends on the region.

Comment: So if there is not _much_ of a difference, what would the (supposedly small) difference be? Wikipedia tells me "a sequence of a finite length $n$ is also called an $n$-tuple", so I do not get the difference in your distinction...

Comment: Their meaning is different, an $n-$tuple is like the co-ordinate of a vector, it's like $(0; 1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, or $(0; -4; 5) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, each of them is an element. You can think of it like this $(a_i)_{i \in I}$ is an element (each $a_i$ is the $i-$coordianete of $(a_i)_{i \in I}$), whereas $\{ a_i \}_{i \in I}$ is a sequence, i.e, a set of elements, where each $a_i$ is an element.

Comment: @Avatar: I don't agree. When $a_i=(-1)^i$ then $$(a_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}=(-1,1,-1,\ldots,(-1)^n)\in \{-1,1\}^n\ ,$$ but  $$\{a_i\}_{1\leq i\leq n}=\{-1,1\}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the author, you find both notations. Lang's definition is something along the following: let $A$ be a set. A family of elements of $A$ indexed by a set $I$ is a map $f:I\rightarrow A$. Now it is common to think of the family $f$ as determining some collection of objects of $A$, and one writes for $f$ also $\left\lbrace a_i\right\rbrace_{i\in I}$ where $a_i\equiv f(i)$. And of course a sequence in $A$ is simply a family of elements of $A$ indexed by the natural numbers $\mathbf{N}$. I think many people are confused about this, because they do not properly distinguish between a map and its range; one cannot identify a family $f:I\rightarrow A$ with its range $\left\lbrace a_i \ | \ i\in I\right\rbrace$.